# Regex find until word of end of block

Tags: python, regex

I'm analyzing router logs and found a solution to find blocks of text, but now I'm facing a problem that the end of the text block might not be present. I'll explain.
This is a sample of a stripped log.

```
POBL026# show run vpn 0
interface ge0/4
  no shutdown
 !
 interface ge0/4.1
  description "TLOC-Extension Custom1"
  ip address 10.31.xxx.1/30
  nat
   respond-to-ping
   log-translations
  !
  tracker     lbo2
  tunnel-interface
   encapsulation ipsec preference 100 weight 33
   color custom1 restrict
   no allow-service bgp
   allow-service dhcp
   allow-service dns
   allow-service icmp
   no allow-service sshd
   no allow-service Netconf
   no allow-service ntp
   no allow-service ospf
   no allow-service stun
   allow-service https
  !
  mtu         1496
  no shutdown
 !
 interface ge0/4.2
  description    "TLOC-Extension biz-internet  "
  ip address 10.31.xxx.5/30
  mtu            1496
  tloc-extension ge0/0
  no shutdown
 !
 ip route 0.0.0.0/0 10.31.xxx.2
 ip route 0.0.0.0/0 84.198.zzz.217
!
POBL026# show run vpn 1
```

So with this code I'm able to isolate each vpn block

```
regex_result = re.search("(?s)(show\s*run\s*vpn\s*" + str(vpn_nbr) + "\s*\n)(.*?)(?=" + routername + ")", filecontent)
```

Then, in each block I searched for the interfaces with this code

```
   result = re.findall("(?s)(?<=interface )(.*?)(?=!)"", vpn_block)
```

But this is not OK as I've noticed that my interface-block itself can hold this sens before the end. So, I could search until the next "!\ninterface", this works fine, but I'm not getting my last block, as there the end is the routername itself.

So I'm looking for a kind of regex that says, everything after the sequence "interface" until "!\ninterface" OR "end of the block".

Can this be done?

Comment: For completeness: what are the values of `vpn_nbr` and `routername` for this particular example?

Comment: Note: there's a double double quote at the end of the last pattern, so that's not copy-pasted from your actual code, since it's a SyntaxError. Please double check that everything is correct if you're not copy-pasting your code.

Comment: What is `vpn_nbr`? Are you doing an `re.search()`  n-times in the same file for n VPN blocks?

Comment: Why not simply do an extra search `re.search("(?s)(?<=interface )(.*?)$", vpn_block)` to get the last block, and add that to `result`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$` character to specify the end of the string.

```
 result = re.findall(r"(?s)(?<=interface )(.*?)(?=!\n\s*interface|$)", vpn_block)
```

The:

```
(?=!\n\s*interface|$)
```

is a positive lookahead that matches until the next `interface`  or the end of block (`|$`).

*Note that you cannot use `$` inside a character class `[]`. Inside `[$]`, `$` loses its special meaning and is a literal character to match.*